# IIS 7.5 MVC 4 Application + Single SSL Client Certificate Required Page

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, virtual-directory, maproute

I am trying to develop an application that will have the ability to log on in two manners, username/password and Client Certificate. I have been unable to create a single page in my IIS web site configuration that will allow for Client Certificate Required for a specific view. I have tried setting Client Certificate Required on the views folder but it does not work. I have tried creating virtual directories to this as well as creating another MVC 4 application and bringing it into my original but the routing never seems to take. Does anyone have any insight to this?

Instructions to nest an MVC 4 application as a Application/Virtual Directory in IIS under an existing MVC 4 application?

Thanks.